# excel vba formula for duplicate entries

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I need a formula to look for last name duplicates.  The formula is

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("M1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(J:J,J1)>1,""Duplicates"","""")"
```

But when I run the macro it results in the below....and has extra parentheses and single quotes.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(J:(J),'J1')>1,"Duplicates","")
```

I must be doing something wrong but do not know what.

Comment: Why are you even using VBA for this?  Why not just put the formula into the cell.

Comment: Did my solution work for you, Chuck?

Comment: Thanks excel hero - yes it does work and this will help me in the future.

Comment: Marc - this is a small part of a macro that copies data from another spreadsheet and I was looking for a way to find suspect duplicates without manually adding the formula to the new sheet.

Comment: COUNTIF(J:J,J1)>1 is a very weird way to achieve a count of all cells with the word "Duplicate" in it. (We have to assume J1 has the text "Duplicate"). Better code might include COUNTA or COUNTIF(J:J,"Duplicate")>1

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using `.FormulaR1C1 =`

Change that to simply `.Formula =`

That's it. That will fix the problem.

On a different note, there is no reason to select the range before doing this (unless you really want it selected after the macro finishes for some reason), but in general this slows down macro execution. While it won't make any significant difference here, the concept is golden when you can eliminate many selections.

Here is how your macro could look with no range selection:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
[m1].Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(J:J,J1)>1,""Duplicates"","""")"
```

Comment: This is a good answer - especially since it notes how to avoid using `.Select`, which is always a good thing.  Can you replace all references of `Range("M1"]` with `[m1]`? Or is there a reason to still use `Range`? (aside from using say `Range(cells(),cells())`? (I.e. is it mainly only suggested to use `[range]` when setting formulas, or can you pretty much use that anywhere `Range()` is used?

Comment: @BruceWayne The square brackets are only a shortcut notation for the Evaluate method. With no dot immediately to the left of the brackets, then they are an abbreviation for `Application.Evaluate()`. But to use them as an abbreviation for `Sheet1.Evaluate()` you would do this `Sheet1.[]`. In either case, what can go inside is any literal text that can be evaluated with the Evaluate method. The key there is LITERAL text; no variables or string building can be used between the square brackets. The long form of Evaluate() is required in those cases.

Comment: @BruceWayne I like to use the square brackets for specifying ranges wherever I might have otherwise used a literal address between quotation marks, like here `Range("A1:A1")`. But it can be used for anything that can be evaluated, and it acts like an array formula in most circumstances, which can be useful sometimes.

Comment: @BruceWayne You are welcome. I should add another thought. Whatever the evaluation results in is what is returned from the square brackets. So if it results in a range, a range comes back. If the evaluation produces an array, an array comes back. If it results in a single (scalar) value, that's what comes back. If the evaluation results in an error then a variant error comes back. Square brackets are extraordinarily powerful, but this power and flexibility puts the responsibility on you to ensure what comes back is appropriate for where and in what context you are using the square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the further thoughts! I also found [this page](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/110856-square-brackets-verses-quotemakrs-visual-basic-applications-ranges.html), and [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52372) one, which discusses using `[]`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Don't believe anyone who tries to say that using the square brackets are bad. That's like the old nonsense about Variants being bad. Both offer tremendous versatility and power at the expense of placing more responsibility on the user. Here is a [much more informative link](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/). And of course I'd be remiss in not including [my own article](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/06/when-working-in-vba-we.html).

Comment: Thank you!! And yeah, whenever anyone says any part of VBA is bad and not to use, I keep in mind there's likely a time and place to use it, given that its used properly. Even `.Select/.Activate` has its uses...

Comment: @HarveyFrench What is the point of writing this comment here? The formula comes from the OP. I merely showed the OP how to assign the formula to the range without it being corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing R1c1 with regular reference.  Use this for r1c1,

`"=IF(COUNTIF(C[9],R1C10)>1,""Duplicates"","""")"`

`C[9]` is a relative reference (akin to just `J`), whereas R1C10 is an absolute reference (row 1, cell 10 = `$J$10`).

Answer (score -2):

Your question is unanswerable as you do not include enough details.

The single quotes are appearing as excel is trying to fix the formula.

You need to lookup how COUNTIF works (the second parameter is used for the criteria)

You also need to enter a formula into the cell manually and get it to work first.  You need to provide this formula in your question.

Using "FormulaR1C1" will require you to provide a R1C1 style of formula.   You might want to use this property instead so that you can use the normal "A1" style of addressing cells:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=A1"
```

`COUNTIF(J:J,J1)>1`    is a very weird way to achieve a count of all cells with the word "Duplicate" in it.  (I am assuming J1 has the text "Duplicate").

Better code might include `COUNTA` or `COUNTIF(J:J,"Duplicate")>1`

Comment: It looks like he's mixing the R1C1 style and regular style - his answer is just to fix the references.  His countif works too, it's simply checking to see if `countif` is greater than 1, it returns `TRUE`, and then follows the `if()` statement.